# Reloading returns Cannot GET error on MEAN Stack (Angular 6, Express)

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I'm having trouble with routing on my MEAN stack application. I have the routing working when testing the site through the Angular development server (using `ng serve` and then viewing at localhost:4200). However, when I try to use solely the Express server that I built out for the backend, I run into some problems. The problem is that although the site works well, even for routing to all the static pages served after running `ng build`, when reloading or navigating to a page from the address bar rather than the links on the page, I'm met with a

> "Cannot GET" error.

The routing is defined in the app.module.ts file within the Angular generated folder. It looks like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, // accessible to all
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, // accessible to all
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, // accessible to all
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, UserAuthGuard]}, // only accessible by users
  {path: 'ridequeue', component: RidequeueComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, VolunteerAuthGuard]}, // Volunteers and Administrators only
  {path: 'viewusers', component: ViewusersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, VolunteerAuthGuard]}, // Volunteers and Administrators only
  {path: 'manageusers', component: ManageusersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdministratorAuthGuard]}, // Administrators only
  {path: 'adminpanel', component: AdminpanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdministratorAuthGuard]}, // Administrators only
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, UserAuthGuard]}, // only accessible by users
  {path: 'feedback', component: FeedbackComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, UserAuthGuard]}, // only accessible by users
  {path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]} // accessible to all
];
```

It is implemented in this file using `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` within the import list.

As for the routing within the Express app, I have the routes configured for the different APIs accessed, and for directing where to go for the static site (the frontend created through Angular, I have:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Other information that may be relevant: I'm using Express 4.16 with CORS middleware, Angular 6, and Chrome to test it.

How to fix it?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: This might [help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback)

Comment: That second one worked well for me @Vikas, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this issue was to add middleware to my Express app to ensure that a fallback was enabled - to navigate to index.html when there isn't a file to serve. I ended up trying both [`express-history-api-fallback`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) and [`connect-history-api-fallback`](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback). Both solved the problem after a bit of configuration but I stuck with the Express one since it was built specifically for Express.